# .net: does anyone know a free library to download nntp messages

Tags: .net, nntp

I'm using ip*works for downloading newsgroup messages and inserting them into a database. ipworks is "comfortable" to use because it automatically splits nntp data return into different objects (or variables). So I have "author" "date" "topic" "messagge" already split for my use.

However ipworks isn't free and it costs a lot for my use.  So I'm looking for a component or code snippet to use to download and "manage" nntp messagges.

Thanks in advance and regards!

Answer (score 0):

IF you're just reading text messages it's not that difficult to write the code, there's plenty of tutorials on the net for it. However, here's one C# class that might help [DougNews.NNTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dougnewsnntp/).